# Trying to change "non command" color in kitty terminal (ver. 0.21.2) using the fish (ver. 3.3.1) shell with the oh-my-fish theme slacker

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, fish, kitty

I've been trying to change the color of non-command such as the picture below (the uncompleated 'help')
[image]

link to the theme im using in omf: https://github.com/maqboolkhan/omf-theme-slacker

my kitty.conf (kitty terminal config) looks like this:

```
background #3a3d4b
foreground #eaf2f1

cursor #eaf2f1
cursor_text_color #000000
selection_foreground #3a3d4b
selection_background #eaf2f1

# dull black
color0 #3a3d4b
# light black
color8 #696d77

# dull red
color1 #ff657a
# light red
color9 #ff657a

# dull green
color2 #bad761
# light green
color10 #bad761

# yellow
color3 #ffd76d
# light yellow
color11 #ffd76d

# blue
color4 #ff9b5e
# light blue
color12 #ff9b5e

# magenta
color5 #c39ac9
# light magenta
color13 #c39ac9

# cyan
color6 #9cd1bb
# light cyan
color14 #9cd1bb

# dull white
color7 #eaf2f1
# bright white
color15 #eaf2f1

# Fonts
font_family Hack Nerd Font Mono
italic_font auto
bold_font auto
bold_italic_font auto
font_size 16.0

background_opacity 1
```

And my config.fish (fish shell config) looks like this:

```
if status is-interactive
    # Commands to run in interactive sessions can go here
    zoxide init fish | source
end

# neofetch | lolcat --seed=210 --freq=0.01
neofetch | lolcat --seed=155 --freq=0.05

#My aliases:
#-- Navigation
alias cd..="cd .."
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."
alias ....="cd ../../.."

#-- listing
alias ll="ls -l"

#-- xclip/copying
alias kopi="xclip -selection clipboard"

#-- open file manager
alias files="xdg-open ."

#-- Neofetch
alias catfetch="neofetch | lolcat --seed=155 --freq=0.05"

#-- valgrind
alias vgtest="valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes"

#-- grepping
alias 5grep="grep --color=auto --context=5"
alias grep="grep --color=auto"
```

I've also tried using
`fish_config browse`
Which when i selected a theme did this:

```
Web config started at file:///tmp/web_configi7995hl8.html
Hit ENTER to stop.
$ set -L
$ set -U fish_color_normal normal
$ set -U fish_color_command F8F8F2
$ set -U fish_color_quote F1FA8C
$ set -U fish_color_redirection 8BE9FD
$ set -U fish_color_end 50FA7B
$ set -U fish_color_error FFB86C
$ set -U fish_color_param FF79C6
$ set -U fish_color_comment 6272A4
$ set -U fish_color_match --background=brblue
$ set -U fish_color_selection white --bold --background=brblack
$ set -U fish_color_search_match bryellow --background=brblack
$ set -U fish_color_history_current --bold
$ set -U fish_color_operator 00a6b2
$ set -U fish_color_escape 00a6b2
$ set -U fish_color_cwd green
$ set -U fish_color_cwd_root red
$ set -U fish_color_valid_path --underline
$ set -U fish_color_autosuggestion BD93F9
$ set -U fish_color_user brgreen
$ set -U fish_color_host normal
$ set -U fish_color_cancel -r
$ set -U fish_pager_color_completion normal
$ set -U fish_pager_color_description B3A06D yellow
$ set -U fish_pager_color_prefix normal --bold --underline
$ set -U fish_pager_color_progress brwhite --background=cyan
```

Which should change the color of the non-command to this:
[image]

Yet it still looks like this:
[image]

Oh and here are my specs and such:

[image]

Comment: The color that is used for incomplete commands is $fish_color_error. What does `set --show fish_color_error` say?

Comment: @faho the output of ```set --show fish_color_error``` is ```$fish_color_error: set in universal scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$fish_color_error[1]: |ff0000|
```

Comment: A quick google led me to this site: https://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/index.html, which led me to ```set fish_color_error red``` any idea on how to make this a hex color?

Comment: Turnsout you simply need to type in the hex code without the '#'.

Comment: Sidenote: Those docs are over 10 years out of date. You want https://fishshell.com/docs/3.3/ for *your* version (or just enter `help` to probably see a local copy). Which is also outdated, but at least only 2 years (and about 15% of all commits ever made to fish)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into it. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?